# Can someone help identify this statue?

Tags: united-states, identification

please if anyone can give any info on a statue my aunt found in her garden (elkton oregon)[image]

Comment: Most would consider the ancient-history and united-states tags to be mutually exclusive. Where did you fish this out of?

Comment: my aunt found it buried in her back garden, also i didnt know what to tag as im new i just wanted to help her get ome info

Comment: Most likely a previous resident's garden decoration, purchased at the garden store. It's flat on top so that a flowerpot can be put on top.

Comment: Any markings on the bottom or back? What material does it appear to be made from? Approximate size? Please add (edit into your question)  any details which might assist us in the identification of this item.

Comment: The United States is a big place. Could you narrow it a bit? Like what state, or even region was it found? Unfortunately, a back garden in itself doesn't give us a lot to go on.

Comment: Looks like a nun in her habit

Comment: Thanks for all your comments I have asked my aunt to send more info to me, she lives in Elkton Oregon. I live in the uk so it takes time to get a response due to time difference but as soon as I know more I will update the question (I have also asked her to send me pictures of the back, top and bottom

Answer (score 3):

I'm agreeing with @Spencer in the comments here. I'm not an expert on this (there are I'm certain people at universities nearby the find in Oregon who are), but that doesn't look like a [Pacific Northwest tribal iconography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Coast_art) to me, and the only stone I could find evidence of them using in their art was [agrillite](https://spiritsofthewestcoast.com/collections/haida-argillite-carvings), which is a soft black shale-like rock.

They much preferred working in [wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totem_pole) or [whalebone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrimshaw). That picture just looks like the quasi-occult type of things modern people like to put on their garden statuary.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. There is a chance it might be of Native American origin. (Elkton is a small town in the Oregon Coast range.) One has to admit that we did too efficient of a job eliminating all traces of their culture; it may be an artifact from one of them. IMHO, there are some superficial similarities to figurines found at one site in SW Washington.

Have you contacted someone at either the Portland Art Museum or the University of Oregon Museum of Natural and Cultural History? They have Native American collections, which means they have people on staff who could give you a better answer than some random person on the Internet. (Or if it is a collectible garden ornament, they might also know.)

Clarification: By the "figurines found at one site in SW Washington", I was referring to the Shoto Clay figurines. Many years ago I purchased Robert Slocum & Kenneth Matsen, *Shoto Clay: Clay Artifacts From the Lower Columbia River* (Binford & Mort, 1968), which reports the discovery of a series of fired clay figurines. I still have the book, but I'm at work so I can't provide any further details about this excavation at the moment.

A catalogue of these enigmatic figurines, David Heath, *Shoto Clay - Wares from the Lake River Ceramics Horizon of Southwest Washington State, Part 1 - Figurines* can be found on archive.org [here](https://archive.org/details/Figurines_Part_1/page/n45/mode/2up).

As I said before, there's a superficial resemblance so I may be wrong, but I had to remark on the similarities.) After all, querying either of the two institutions I mentioned above, or the authors of these works, might lead somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Interesting stuff.

Comment: As for the location, it looks like the find is in what the good old [USGS map](https://www.loc.gov/resource/g3701e.ct003648r/?r=-0.062,0.113,0.309,0.152,0) calls Suislaw territory (although that map is at best a snapshot of what should properly be a movie).